# SQL integrity constraints primary and foreign keys

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I am following some examples and the following should work, but I am getting some errors. Can someone tell me what is wrong?

```
/*  Data Definition */

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS
        (CUST_NO        INTEGER         ,
        CUST_NAME       VARCHAR(40)     ,
        STREET          VARCHAR(40)     ,
        TOWN            VARCHAR(40)     ,
        POSTCODE        INTEGER         ,
        CR_LIMIT        INTEGER         ,
        CURR_BALANCE    INTEGER         ,
        PRIMARY KEY (CUST_NO)
        );

CREATE TABLE PRODUCTS
        (PROD_COD       VARCHAR(10)     ,
        DESCRIPTION     VARCHAR(50)     ,
        PROD_GROUP      CHAR(1)         , 
        LIST_PRICE      INTEGER         ,
        QTY_ON_HAND     INTEGER         ,
        REMAKE_LEVEL    INTEGER         ,
        REMAKE_QTY      INTEGER         ,
        PRIMARY KEY (PROD_COD)
        );

CREATE TABLE ORDERS
        (ORDER_NO       INTEGER         ,
        ORDER_DATE      DATE            ,
        CUST_NO         INTEGER         ,
        PRIMARY KEY (ORDER_NO),
        FOREIGN KEY (CUST_NO) REFERENCES CUSTOMERS(CUST_NO)
);

CREATE TABLE ORDER_DETAILS
        (ORDER_NO       INTEGER         ,
        PROD_COD        VARCHAR(10)     ,
        ORDER_QTY       INTEGER         ,
        ORDER_PRICE     INTEGER         ,
        PRIMARY KEY (ORDER_NO, PROD_COD),
        FOREIGN KEY (ORDER_NO) REFERENCES ORDERS(ORDER_NO),
        FOREIGN KEY (PROD_COD) REFERENCES PRODUCTS(PROD_COD)
);
```

And I am getting these errors when I try to insert values in to the tables:
[image]

I can't work it out as it seems that I am referencing the right things, but obviously I am not.

Is it because of the composite primary key? That seemed to work in the example.

I am using Oracle SQL Developer 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem you are trying to insert an order for a customer that does not exist.  Is there a row in customers with cust_no = 13144 ?

Comment: Yes, maybe that is the problem. Will test.

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thanks.